# How to get all values from same column?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am developing web framework using python. below is my database. this database name is fruit.

```
name     price
-----    -----
apple    $2
pear     $2
grape    $4
```

I am using SQLAlchemy. so class name is Fruit. What should I write to make result below list ..? I want to get values from 'name' column.

['apple', 'pear', 'grape']

and is there any way to execute SQL query directly ..?

```
sql_query = 'SELECT name FROM Fruit'
Fruit.query.execute(<sql_query>)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a model called `Fruit`, to make the database send us only the column(s) you want instead of pulling everything and then filtering the field you want in Python, you can use:

```
for fruint_name in session.query(Fruit.name):
     # do something with fruit_name
```

If you don't want duplicates you can use:

```
for fruint_name in session.query(Fruit.name).distinct():
     # do something with fruit_name
```

Comment: distinct method was a life saver.

Answer (score 7):

One option:

```
fruit_names = [fruit.name for fruit in Fruit.query.all()]
```